# Как в Gulp создать хеш-файла и записать его?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, frontend

Всем привет.
Требуется до минификации файла, создать его хеш и записать этот файл с хешом, и в добавок, записать в другой файл название файла до и после.
То есть:
я минифицирую файл main.js
записываю как допустим main.min.8954751.js
и еще в каком-то файле, result.json у меня записываются название этих файлов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задачу решил следующим образом

```
let gulp = require('gulp'), // Подключаем Gulp
    plumber = require('gulp-plumber'), // Обработка ошибок (error handling)
    csso = require('gulp-csso'), // сжатие css
    filenames = require('gulp-filenames'),
    hash = require('gulp-hash-filename'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'); // Подключаем библиотеку для переименования файлов

gulp.task('css_main', function() {
    return gulp.src(paths.app.main.css.src)
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
        .pipe(csso())
        .pipe(hash({
            'format': '{name}._{hash}_{ext}'
        }))
        .pipe(filenames('css_main'))
        .on('end', function () {
            let names = {}, data = filenames.get('css_main');
            for (let key in data) {
                let str = data[key];
                let strKey = str.replace(/\._.*_/g, '');
                names[strKey] = str;
            }
            fs.writeFile('css_main.json', JSON.stringify(names), 'utf8', function (err) {});
        })
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.app.main.css.dest));
});
```

Таким образом получаю json

```
{
  "base.min.css": "base.min._21cb27b9b65c7c20f7933871f5332608_.css",
  "print.min.css": "print.min._17bb5b028bda2d3a732c39e60751ccf7_.css"
}
```

В PHP можно читать этот json, и при подключение стилей указывать ключ стилей, и не нужно будет редактировать это подключение если стили поменяются, ведь все кешируется